# How do you access the Label of a Table field column with a Type of Dropdown?

Tags: matrix, table-field, drop-down

How do you access the Label of a Table field column with a Type of Dropdown?

I have a Table field in a Matrix block and one of the column types is a Dropdown. When I use the `{{ row.handle }}` syntax for the Dropdown type, I can only access the Value, not the Label. `{{ row.dropdownHandle.label }}` does not work.

I [looked at the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/table-fields.html) but there doesn't seem to be a mention of the Dropdown type and how to access the label.

Comment: I would also like to know this

Comment: Me too! Did you resolve it?